# Why can't ASP.NET be hosted on a linux server?

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting

ASP.NET is open source so shouldn't it be able to be hosted on any server just like a web app written in any other open source language such as php not limited to a windows server?

Comment: Mono can run ASP.NET, or there's .NET Core. Your question shows a lack of research into the available options.

Comment: Whether something is open source or not has little relevance to which platforms it can or can't run on. Something can be open sourced and only run on Windows, or it can be closed source and only run on Linux. Someone somewhere has to take the time to make it cross platform, which is admittedly easier when the source is open but still not trivial.

Comment: I removed my answer.  But it should be noted that my answer was specific to the question, in explaining that ASP.NET itself is not open source.  The question did not ask for an open source alternative.  Whatever...  As long as everyone is happy.

Comment: [ASP.NET](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/) itself is actually open source (at least significant chunks of it - not sure if 100% is)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ASP.NET Core, the latest version](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#centos) (still in preview) in fact can be run on Linux.

Previous versions of ASP.NET have a dependency on the .NET Framework which only runs on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you can via [ASP.NET Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/aspnet/), and in fact Mono has support [up to ASP.NET 4.0 and MVC 3](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/).

The limiting factor really is IIS doesn't run on *nix, so you'll not be able to use the configuration aspects of the projects, but you can run the code via Apache modules or FastCGI.

The ASP.NET framework isn't open source (it has too many dependencies on internal code) but ASP.NET MVC and the new .NET Core, and ASP.NET Core releases are.

But just because something's open source, doesn't mean it "runs everywhere" it just means that you have some rights to look at the code, and typically can do things with that - someone still has to write an engine that can interpret and run your code on another operating system.